# Query to find unique record exist or not using sql developer returning either true or false

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, spring-jdbc

I would like to have a query to find if a unique record exist or not in the database. For instance:

```
SELECT externaleventid 
  FROM event 
 WHERE externaleventid = "XYZ".
```

If "XYZ" doesn't exist, it should return as false and if exist it should return as true. I am using sql developer and eclipse. I tried using

```
if exists (select externaleventid from  event where externaleventid='XYZ') 
select 'True'  
else 
select 'False' 
return
```

but it is giving me an Syntax error  "and/or" expected in sql developer.

Comment: `select nvl2(max(externaleventid), 'True', 'False') from event where externaleventid = 'XYZ'`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you are asking for a SQL statement that returns the string `'True'` or `'False'` or whether you are asking for a PL/SQL function that returns that same string or whether you are asking for a PL/SQL function that returns an actual boolean.  The boolean data type didn't exist in SQL prior to 12.1 so I'm guessing that you're not asking for a SQL statement that returns a boolean.

If you want a single SQL statement, you could do something like

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN cnt >= 1
             THEN 'True'
             ELSE 'False'
          END) result_str
  FROM( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
          FROM event 
         WHERE externaleventid = 'XYZ' )
```

If you want a PL/SQL function, you'd probably do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION does_exist( 
    p_externaleventid IN event.externaleventid%type 
)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  l_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM event
   WHERE externaleventid = p_externaleventid;

  IF( l_cnt > 0 )
  THEN 
    RETURN 'True';
  ELSE
    RETURN 'False';
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This query will work for me. SELECT (CASE WHEN cnt >= 1
             THEN 'True'
             ELSE 'False'
          END) result_str
  FROM( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
          FROM event 
         WHERE externaleventid = 'XYZ' )